# Merge changes in a Git repo to TFVC branch

Tags: git, merge, tfvc

I understnad how to work with Git repos and TFVC, I understand that in TFS 2018, we can have 1 TFVC a nd 1 or more Git repos.
In case 1 team continues to work on TFVC and another team works on Git repos, is possible or how merge changes dont in the Git repo to the TFVC main branch? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This isn't built in functionality, TFVC and Git are 2 completely separate version control systems with very different paradigms, i.e. TFVC is a centralized VCS and Git is Distributed.

You can integrate them however you'll need to use one of the following.

[git-tfs](http://git-tfs.com/) a 3rd party product that provides good integration. This only works on windows

[git-tf](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30474) microsofts integration tool. It's cross platform and runs on Windows, MacOS and Linux however is less featureful than git-tfs

If you need simple integration then either should suffice, however note that both of them are designed to allow users to follow a git workflow locally whilst integrating with TFVC.

Ultimately, if teams are expected to develop on the same code-base, on a regular cadence, then they are probably better off using the same repository.